# Is generating usable entanglement difficult?

Tags: entanglement, experimental-realization

I'm a theorist and I assume that I can use entanglement resources for practical use freely, but is this really the case? Is generating entanglement and storing it for long enough periods of time such that it can be consumed a realistic assumption? For example, is it a much longer process with respect to performing logic gates on qubits?

For example in quantum algorithms or protocols involving entanglement consumption, like quantum clock synchronization for one. Say the algorithm/protocol needs to be repeated often, continuous clock synchronization lets say. Would entanglement generation be a bottleneck in "realistic" scenarios?

I read about different types of qubits and how entanglement can be generated between them in a lab, but I can't seem to find information about how fast the process is or if it is a deterministic process for each qubit type. I did find some results regarding deterministic entanglement generation, but I couldn't find any metric regarding how fast the process can be repeated.

Any tips regarding speed or difficulty of quantum entanglement generation would help me a lot, or even just some general insights.

Comment: I think you can generate entangled photons pretty easily then send one of them via laser or optical fiber, so any protocol which uses EPR pairs (teleportation) can just generate them on the fly rather than storing them. Photons are cheap, so if you lose one it's no big deal.